# Linear Algebra Problem regarding the form $x^TAx$

Tags: linear-algebra, contest-math

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Show that there is a column vector $x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$, such that:
$$x^{T}Ax=TrA, \quad x^{T}x=n.$$

I have tried to apply some tricks, such as multiplication with $x^{T}$ or $x$, but I do not take something useful. Also, I have found this relation $x^TAx = Tr(xx^TA)$ that could potentially be useful, but all of my tries were unsuccessful.
Any advice on how to approach this problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried the $2\times 2$? This is generally helpful for $n\times n$ matrices.

Comment: Hi may I ask which contest was this problem in?  :)

Comment: @AdityaEkbote, it is a problem from the IMC 2021 selection test of my university.

Comment: @DimitrisMinagias nice, it looks fun! But alas  my limited knowledge cannot solve these problems although I would love to try this!

Comment: Consider $A-{1\over n}Tr(A)\,I.$ Then the problem should be easier to handle.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc, from the fact that $Tr(x^TAx)=Tr(xx^TA)$, I obtained the relation $X^{T}(A-\frac{1}{n}Tr(A))=0$, but I do not know how to proceed. This was one of my initial insticts when I saw the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer to use inner product $\langle x,y\rangle $ instead of $y^tx.$
Let $B={1\over 2}(A+A^t).$ Then $Tr(B)=Tr(A)$ and $B$ is a symmetric matrix. Hence it admits an orthonormal basis $v_1,v_2,\ldots, v_n$ consisting of eigenevectors of $B$ with eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2,\ldots, \lambda_n.$ Take $x=v_1+v_2+\ldots +v_n.$ Then $x^tx=\langle x, x\rangle =n$ and
$$\langle Ax,x\rangle =\langle Bx,x\rangle =\sum_{k=1}^n\sum_{l=1}^n\langle Bv_k,v_l\rangle =\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_k=Tr(B)=Tr(A).$$

Answer (score 2):

Proof sketch:

Let $e_k$ be the unit vector with $k$th element $1$ and other element $0$. So, we know that $\sqrt{n} e_k$ has $L_2$ norm $\sqrt{n}$. Also, notice that

$$\frac{1}n\sum_{k=1}^n (\sqrt{n}e_k)^TA(\sqrt{n}e_k)=Tr(A)$$

This means that the average $(\sqrt{n}e_k)^TA(\sqrt{n}e_k)$ is $Tr(A)$, so, there is some $e_i$ with $(\sqrt{n}e_i)^TA(\sqrt{n}e_i)\le Tr(A)$ and there is some $e_j$ with $(\sqrt{n}e_j)^TA(\sqrt{n}e_j)\ge Tr(A)$. So, consider a continuous curve from $\sqrt{n}e_i$ to $\sqrt{n}e_j$ on the sphere $x^Tx=n$ (say, $\sqrt{n}(\cos t e_i+\sin t e_j)$ for $t\in[0,\pi/2]$), since $x^TAx$ is continuous, by the intermediate value theorem, there must be some point on the curve that satisfies $x^TAx=Tr(A)$.